# python fractions - dash being parsed as "2013" => Invalid literal for Fraction:

Tags: python, scrapy

Using scrapy to get recipes, having trouble parsing the strings:

I am attempting to parse this string "1 – 1 1/2 cup Grated Raw Cauliflower"

and the dash is being interpreted by python as a the following

"ValueError: Invalid literal for Fraction: u'\u2013' "

Is there anyway I can error handle so the whole program doesn't throw?

Overview:

use regex to parse string into number, measurement, item.
convert to float
detect fraction
convert fraction to float

I used a try/except to simply err on the "min" side of the range provided, though I'd ideally like to have both somehow

```
if re.compile("[^\W\d]").search(quantity):
            match = re.compile("[^\W\d]").search(quantity)
            amount = s[:match.start()]
            grocery = s[item.start():]                                
            if '/' not in amount:
              amount = float(amount)
            elif '/' in amount:                  
              def tryAmount(amount):
                  try:
                    return round(float(sum(Fraction(s) for s in amount.split())), 2)
                  except ValueError:
                    return amount[0]
              amount= tryAmount(amount)
            else:
              amount = amount[0]
```

Comment: could you please share your code?

Comment: Did you think of using `replace` with a regular hyphen?

Comment: That's not a plain dash; it's an "em dash" or "long dash".  It's not a plain ASCII character.

Comment: I tried using the utf-8 encoding at the top and still could not "replace" it with a regular hyphen. I'll include my code with my workaround

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's work it through:

```
quantity = "1 – 1 1/2 cup Grated Raw Cauliflower"
match = re.compile("[^\W\d]").search(quantity)
```

So `match.group(0)` is `c`, meaning `amount = s[:match.start()]` sets `amount` to be `"1 – 1 1/2 "`

`amount.split()` would then be `['1', '\xe2\x80\x93', '1', '1/2']` (or `['1', '–', '1', '1/2']` if printed) and you're passing each value to `Fraction()`, which can't take the em-dash, or even a hyphen:

```
>>> Fraction('–')
...
ValueError: Invalid literal for Fraction: '\xe2\x80\x93'
```

The comprehension `sum(Fraction(s) for s in amount.split()))` won't do what you want anyway: If it worked as written it would add up `1`, `1` and `0.5` to give `2.5`, which is above the suggested value of 'between 1 and 1.5'.

I think you may need to revisit your approach to extracting numbers, and interpreting ranges in the recipes!

Comment: this was a very well-thought out response. I will need to incorporate handling for ranges